dotNet Core "request matched multiple endpoints" but listed matches are identical
dotNet Core (same behavior in 5 and 6) call to GET endpoints return this error:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
Sage100_API.Controllers.ShipToController.GetShipTo (Sage100_API)
Sage100_API.Controllers.ShipToController.GetShipTo (Sage100_API)
As you can see, the matches are identical.  There is only one GetShipTo routine in the project.
I have another very similar project with the same controller code and it works just fine.

Please show us relevant code to help us understand better your scenario and problem.

Even if you don't have 2 methods with the same name.
Check if you have 2 methods whose routing is the same, for example: 2 GET functions without defining a personal ROUTE for each method. If you do have two methods with the same routing, make sure to make a [Route] for one of the methods.
For example:
    //Get
    [HttpGet]
     [Route("get")]
     public List<workerobj> Get()=>
     worker.Get();
    //Get first
     [HttpGet]
     [Route("getFirst")]
     public List<workerobj> GetFirst()=>
     worker.GetFirst();

If I didn't do [ROUTE] to the getFirst() method, then when I make a request I would have an ambiguity error,
Because I have two GET methods that do not accept parameters.

Thank you - that was it  copied one line too many from one controller to the next!
